# 1 decision tree has 2^d nodes at most, How many nodes for n decision trees?

Tags: tree, binary-tree, decision-tree, binary-decision-diagram

1 decision tree has 2^d nodes at most,

How many nodes for n decision trees?

n*(2^d), or 2^(nd), or 1+2+...+2^d, or anything else?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If all the trees have the same number of node [image: 2^d], and all the trees are distinct (no shared node), then there are [image: n*(2^d)] nodes for [image: n] trees.

If the trees have different numbers of nodes (tree [image: i] has [image: 2^{d_i}] nodes), then the total number of nodes is: [image: \sum_{i=1}^n{2^{d_i}}] nodes.

Answer (score 0):

`n*(2^d)`

Personally, I think you should provide more details about your question. For example, if those n decision trees share some nodes, the answer should be different.